# Double RewriteRule with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a problem with my rules; I put both but works only the first.

I have 2 files with different information.

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ tour.php?tour=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ programa.php?programa=$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Only the first one works because the pattern that you use to match is exactly the same: `^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$`. You need something else to separate what does to **tour.php** and what goes to **programa.php**. Right now, if someone types in `http://youdomain.com/abcdefg/` into their browser's URL address bar, the URI `/abcdefg/` gets sent to your server. The first rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ tour.php?tour=$1 [NC,L]
```

matches because `/abcdefg/` matches your pattern `^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$` and it gets rewritten to `/tour.php?tour=abcdefg`. What if that was meant for **programa.php**? The second rule will never be reached because everything is captured by the first rule's pattern. You need to add something else the differentiate between the two. For example, add an extra path note:

```
RewriteRule ^tour/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ tour.php?tour=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^programa/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ programa.php?programa=$1 [NC,L]
```

This means if I go to `http://youdomain.com/programa/abcdefg/`, my request gets rewritten to `/programa.php?programa=abcdefg` and if I go to `http://youdomain.com/tour/abcdefg/`, my request gets rewritten to `/tour.php?tour=abcdefg`.